# my camera no longer displays my background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i wrote a sript that when my Player touches my enemy. my Player respawn should know that my camera is following my player. But when I respawn, she moves behind my background

how to do?

My scipt

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform spawnPoint;
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
  {
    if (col.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
      col.transform.position = spawnPoint.position;

  }
}
```

//Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you could do:

1. Use z axis to place object (player) in front.
2. Use sorting layers and sorting group component.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: What did you try?